# How do deep learning model store the mean and standard deviation and how to run sampling?

Tags: deep-learning

GPT-3 can generate code
But distribution learning is just learnt the repeated things and no ordering of code if sampling

Is deep learning model a storage of mean and standard deviation?

How can mean and standard deviation stored as the format of deep learning model?

How can python model.predict do like sampling from distribution?

**Update**

How GPT-3 code generation make learning has ordering of code in reasonable way when using model.predict to output code?

Is deep learning of GPT-3 no statistics meaning?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Please, clarify the question so that we can help.